# Python: how to replace by blank or NA as exception in a list of properties?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I tried google some hours without solution.
So created this account try to ask by myself.
I am using python to generate a user list and export as csv.
I can `print(Users['Id'],Users['Name'])` without error as all users have these two fields.
But if I `print(Users['Id'],Users['Name'],Users['Email'])`,
I met errors, if I write `try` and `exception` as pass, I got only one user result `S3 alex` as only alex has the field Email.
May I know if there is a way that I can put all the 6 field names as the table header.
Then whenever a user has no value on any fields, just put `NA` or leave it blank ? Thanks.

My code looks like this:

```
fo=open('Userlist.csv','w',newline='')

data_obj=csv.writer(fo)

data_obj.writerow(['cnt','Name','Id'])

cnt=1

result = get_users()

for user in result['Users']:

   print(user['Name'],user['Id']) # to see result

   data_obj.writerow([user['Name'],user['Id']])  # to write data into csv rows

   row_number += 1

fo.close()
```

```
#If I print(result), get below result with different fields:

    "Users": [
        {
            "Id": "S-1xxxx",
            "Name": "S1 Peter",
            "State": "DISABLED",
            "UserRole": "USER"
        },
        {
            "Id": "S-2xxxx",
            "Name": "S2 Mary",
            "State": "DISABLED",
            "UserRole": "USER"
        },
        {
            "Id": "S-3xxxx",
            "Email": "alex@domain.com",
            "Name": "S3 alex",
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "UserRole": "USER",
            "EnabledDate": "2020-1-5"
        },
        {
            "Id": "S-4xxxx",
            "Name": "S3 brand",
            "State": "DELETED",
        }]

[expected result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIMMB.png
```

Comment: Always post you results to the question instead of attaching an external link

Comment: Don't post images of text and watch your formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open("Userlist.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(["Id", "Name", "Email"])
    for user in users:
        w.writerow([user.get("Id"), user.get("Name"), user.get("Email")])
```

The `with` keyword causes python to use a context manager and means you don't need to worry about closing your file. It's not vital to this solution, but it's good practice.

Using `get()` looks for your key and returns None if it doesn't exist, thus not throwing an error if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks so much! It fixed my question and good to have an extra suggestion, too.
It can print perfectly but met below error at writing to csv, which was fixed by using exception by pass:
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-11: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` to your `open()` function call: `open("Userlist.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")`. If that doesn't work then check the headers sent by the server in your API response and look for the text encoding under 'Content-Type', then replace "utf-8" if your results are in a different encoding.